# Proving the basis of an eigenspace is not the same for a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

With the information given in #18, prove that $A$ and $A^T$ need not have the same eigenspaces (I would use a 2x2 matrix, as #18 posits).

Clarification: DO NOT solve #18. Using the information in #18, prove that $A$ and $A^T$ need not have the same eigenspaces. I know that for any $A$ and $A^T$, the eigenvalues are equivalent, but how would I go about showing they don't necessarily have the same eigenspaces (using #18)?

Their respective solution spaces for

$(\lambda I - A)x = 0$

would be different, and that's what I'm assuming. But I'm not sure how to use the info in #18 to prove it. Any help on this one?

Comment: It is frustrating to try to read an image sideways.  When uploading an image, please have it oriented correctly before hand.  That being said, without reading the question from the book, what is the kernel of $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$?  What is the kernel for $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$?  Now, remember that the kernel is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$.  Are they the same?  What does this prove?  *Note:* some matrices will have the same eigenbasis as their transpose (trivially symmetric matrices do).  We just need one counterexample to show it isn't always true

Comment: @JMoravitz I apologize, thank you for the advice! And no they are not.